# Send http response to multiple clients in python

Tags: python, http, httprequest

**little bit explanation:**
i have multiple clients and a very simple http client written in python.
 out of all the clients , one client sends a post request to the http server with 4 values (lets call this client "client Alpha") and all the remaining clients send the http post request just to establish the connection to the server (lets call these clients "clients beta") the reason behind clients beta for sending the request is so that they can receive the values that were sent via client alpha...

```
import kwargs
import args

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import logging
import requests
class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def _set_response(self):
    self.send_response(200,1)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'int')
    self.end_headers()

def breakRequest(self, str):
    l = []
    x = str.split("&")
    for i in x:
        a = i.split("=")
        l.append(a[1])
    return l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3]

def do_POST(self):
    content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
    post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself
    var1,var2,var3,var4 = self.breakRequest(str(post_data.decode('utf-8')))
    if (var1 !='ard'):
        s = "\n" + var1+"\n"+var2+"\n"+var3 + "\n"+var4 + "\n"
        logging.info(s)
        logging.info("POST request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n\nBody:\n%s\n",
            str(self.path), str(self.headers), post_data.decode('utf-8'))

    self._set_response()
    self.wfile.write("1".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))    

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=6060):
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
  server_address = ('', port)
  httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
  logging.info('Starting httpd...\n')
  try:
     httpd.serve_forever()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
httpd.server_close()
logging.info('Stopping httpd...\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
 from sys import argv

 if len(argv) == 2:
     run(port=int(argv[1]))
 else:
     run()
```

**what the client alpha sends:**
client alpha sends 4 values which are being stored in var1, var2, var3, var4

**what client beta sends**
client beta send http post request only once to establish the connection to the server

**what i am trying to achieve**
 once the client beta has establish the connection to the server i am trying to make the server store the values received by the client alpha into var1,var2,va3,var4 and then send these values  out to all the beta clients at once once the values have been sent out then wait and when the new values are received by the server from client alpha, then send these new values to the client beta

every time the ip address of beta client  is changed then it sends the request again to establish connection.
and

i am not very good at python and what i currently have is all thanks to google i kept searching for the examples and been implementing and testing them and ended up with a python code that receives and stores the http post data into variables 
i will highly appreciate your help 
thanks in advance 
and sorry for any mistakes

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about having the server connected to 4 different clients and PUSHING data to them when a specific event occurs. You are going to need to look at either using Websockets (https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) or Server Sent Events (https://medium.com/code-zen/python-generator-and-html-server-sent-events-3cdf14140e56).

Those are the only two methods in which a server can push data to other clients, as they are connected, so the server knows that they exist.